# Datanitro - Create a sheet that has data validation in it?

Tags: datanitro

I have one sheet (let's call it sheet1) that has a range of cells A1 to A20 filled. My python script is going to create a new sheet (sheet2) and fill in a few cells.  The user then enters in a few other new cells, say B2 to B4. I want those cells (B2 to B4) to have data validation, a list from the cells in sheet1. Is this possible?